# bash how to insert multiple empty lines into a file according to another file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am meeting some difficulties when using bash to insert multiple empty lines into a file (called file1) according to an index file(called file2).
(these files can be treated as passed variables)
the index file (file2) looks like:

```
-
-
-
M
H
A
-
N
X
X
M
-
-
-
F
G
A
...
```

the file1 looks like this:

```
M   x1 y1 z1 m1 n1
H   x2 y2 z2 m2 n2
A   x3 y3 z3 m3 n3
N   x4 y4 z4 m4 n4
X   x5 y5 z5 m5 n5
X   x6 y6 z6 m6 n6
M   x7 y7 z7 m7 n7
F   x8 y8 z8 m8 n8
G   x9 y9 z9 m9 n9
A   x0 y0 z0 m0 n0
...
```

the output should be looks like this:

```
-
-
-
M   x1 y1 z1 m1 n1
H   x2 y2 z2 m2 n2
A   x3 y3 z3 m3 n3
-
N   x4 y4 z4 m4 n4
X   x5 y5 z5 m5 n5
X   x6 y6 z6 m6 n6
M   x7 y7 z7 m7 n7
-
-
-
F   x8 y8 z8 m8 n8
G   x9 y9 z9 m9 n9
A   x0 y0 z0 m0 n0
...
```

if file2 deletes the '-', the content as well as the order will always be the same as the first column in file1.

I tried dataframe in Python to deal with it, but it's too slow. So I was wondering how to use bash to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: would the letters in the index file / file2 always be in the same order as in the data file / file1? I.e. that there's no need think about reordering any lines? I guess so, since the letters in the data file aren't unique, so the rules for reordering would need to be complicated

Comment: Do you really mean bash or do you just mean use the command line? This is a very bad problem for shell programming, are you OK with solutions using awk or perl or any other tool?

Comment: yes, It's always in the same order @ilkkachu
sorry, I thought bash contains awk, sed, grep, etc.@terdon

Comment: @Jiao, Bash is really just the shell, the tool that implements the command-line where you start other commands. Awk and sed etc. are distinct tools but standard. Don't do text processing with just the shell, that's a bad idea :)

Comment: I see. maybe I can just call them bash or shell tools or specify which tool

Comment: The current example is polysemous. It is not clear if you mean to match on first field or just insert empty lines at specified positions. You should include into the question, what happens if first field does not match, or if non-empty-line numbers of two files are different. Also it's not clear if you mean empty lines or dashes.

Comment: @thanasisp.Sorry for that. I did a few modifications to my question. the index file and the first column of the data file will always match if the index file deletes the '-'

Comment: @Jiao you got it now ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the letters in the index file are always the right ones in the right order (so we can ignore which letter we see), and that the empty lines actually contain the dashes and aren't totally empty, maybe this should work:

```
$ awk -v datafile=data.txt '$1 == "-" { print "-"; next} { getline < datafile; print }' < index.txt 
-
-
-
M   x1 y1 z1 m1 n1
H   x2 y2 z2 m2 n2
A   x3 y3 z3 m3 n3
-
N   x4 y4 z4 m4 n4
X   x5 y5 z5 m5 n5
X   x6 y6 z6 m6 n6
M   x7 y7 z7 m7 n7
-
-
-
F   x8 y8 z8 m8 n8
G   x9 y9 z9 m9 n9
A   x0 y0 z0 m0 n0
...
```

It reads the index file one line at a time; if the first field there is exactly `-`, prints that; and otherwise reads and prints a line from the other file. (Which means that if a totally empty line comes up in the index file, it will also go to the next line from the data file.)

Comment: a stupid question: if I use `datafile="$data"` it will not work. So, how to pass that variable?

Comment: @Jiao, hmm, I wonder why not? How exactly are you doing it? `awk -v var=something` sets the awk variable `var` to `something`. So if you have e.g. `foo=123; awk -v bar="$foo" 'BEGIN {print bar}'`, you have the shell variable `foo`, that gets assigned to the awk variable `bar` that the awk script then prints. (Note the `-v`.)

Comment: ```data=`cat data.txt ` ```
```index=`cat index.txt` ```
```awk -v datafile="$data" '$1 == "-" { print "-"; next} { getline < datafile; print }' <(echo "$index")| less ```
the output was the content of $index

Comment: @Jiao, ah, you're loading the whole contents of the files into the `$data` and `$index` variables in the shell. Hmm, I guess you can do that, but one usually doesn't. That makes it harder for the awk script to access the other file. You'd need to do essentially the same as the shell does with the process substitution (`<(...)`). But... do you have to use the variables in between?

Comment: the reality is that I have thousands of files that need to deal with. maybe I can generate them into a tmp folder. Thanks

Comment: @Jiao, you could e.g. loop over them in the shell, e.g. something like `for f in file*.txt ; do ... something with "$f"; done` if it was just one file. With pairs of files it's a bit more annoying, and depends on the files you have. Though even if you have `data=$(cat data.txt)` etc., you still need some way to find the right filename for `cat`...

Comment: Thanks. the file and subfile are quite huge, It's better to save them to the tmp folder. I'll generate an index file for the name to loop over.

Comment: @Jiao is the index file same for all the data files ?

Comment: @guest_7 no, each data file has it's own index file

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU sed, also assuming that the order of the initial letters is strictly the same in the two file ignoring the `-` lines, read and insert one line from `file1` for each "letter" line of `file2`:

```
$ sed -e '/^[A-Z]/{R file1' -e 'd;}' file2
-
-
-
M   x1 y1 z1 m1 n1
H   x2 y2 z2 m2 n2
A   x3 y3 z3 m3 n3
-
N   x4 y4 z4 m4 n4
X   x5 y5 z5 m5 n5
X   x6 y6 z6 m6 n6
M   x7 y7 z7 m7 n7
-
-
-
F   x8 y8 z8 m8 n8
G   x9 y9 z9 m9 n9
A   x0 y0 z0 m0 n0
```

Answer (score 2):

With file2 being the index file
and file1 as the data file, using **POSIX sed** , using the index file we first generate a sed code that will then be applied to the data file to get the final desired output.

```bsh
sed '
  1{
    x;s:.*:H;s/.*/-/;x:;x
    i\
x;s/.*/-/;x
    :loop
      /^-/!d;g;n
    b loop
  }
  /^-/s/.*/G/;t
  c\
n
' file2 |sed -f - file1
```

---

Output:-

```
-
-
-
M   x1 y1 z1 m1 n1
H   x2 y2 z2 m2 n2
A   x3 y3 z3 m3 n3
-
N   x4 y4 z4 m4 n4
X   x5 y5 z5 m5 n5
X   x6 y6 z6 m6 n6
M   x7 y7 z7 m7 n7
-
-
-
F   x8 y8 z8 m8 n8
G   x9 y9 z9 m9 n9
A   x0 y0 z0 m0 n0
```

---

Answer (score 2):

**[1] Perl**
Supply data file on the stdin of Perl program, and take the input from stdin unless the current line begins with a dash.

```bsh
perl -pe '
  $_ = <STDIN> if !/^-/;
' file2 < file1
```

---

**[2] GNU sed**

```bsh
sed '
  /^-/!Rfile1
  $!N;//P;D
' file2
```

---

**[3] Python**

```bsh
python3 -c 'import sys
data_file,index_file = sys.argv[1:]

with open(data_file) as f, open(index_file) as g:
  for l in g:
    var = l if l.startswith("-") else next(f)
    print(var,end="")

' file1 file2
```

---

Answer (score 1):

```
for j in $(awk '/-/{print NR}' file2); do sed -i ''$j'i -' file1; done
```

output

```
cat file1
-
-
-
M   x1 y1 z1 m1 n1
H   x2 y2 z2 m2 n2
A   x3 y3 z3 m3 n3
-
N   x4 y4 z4 m4 n4
X   x5 y5 z5 m5 n5
X   x6 y6 z6 m6 n6
M   x7 y7 z7 m7 n7
-
-
-
F   x8 y8 z8 m8 n8
G   x9 y9 z9 m9 n9
A   x0 y0 z0 m0 n0
```

Comment: The problem here is that you're running one instance of `sed` for each empty line added. That's not as bad as reading input line by line and running five instances of `cut` for every line, but it's still uselessly slow with all the processes being launched (and probably slower than whatever they did with Python dataframe). You could mitigate that by stacking multiple insert commands to the sed script, though I'm not sure how well that would scale. (Also, the quoting in `''$j'i -'` seems off, why not just double-quote the whole thing, `"${j}i -"`?)